# multiple registration of the same geofence

Tags: android, geofencing, android-geofence

I would like to know, how google location services handles multiple registration of the same geofence?

I have read that NEVER_EXPIRES geofences are removed when:

- phone is rebooted
- network location is turned on/off

and only in this situation listed.

So, I am thinking about how to overcome this situations, when phone is for ex. unintentionally rebooted. I came up with registering geofences on application start all over again. 
But now, my question is, what will happen in case, that geofences haven't been actually removed between application re-starts? Will they be replaced?
For example if I register the very same geofence 7x, will associated intent be fired 7x or just once?

Thanks for suggestions and corrections!

Answer (score 3):

Too late to answer, nevertheless, in case it helps somebody:

> So, I am thinking about how to overcome this situations, when phone is
>   for ex. unintentionally rebooted.

You should use broadcast receivers which will listen for:
android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED (to handle re-boot) AND 
android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED (to handle loc on/off)

> I came up with registering geofences on application start all over
>   again.

No. Try to re-register all the geofences in the broadcast receivers as described above. You can start a service to re-register geofences from the onReceive of the above mentioned broadcast receivers.

> But now, my question is, what will happen in case, that geofences
>   haven't been actually removed between application re-starts? Will they
>   be replaced? For example if I register the very same geofence 7x, will
>   associated intent be fired 7x or just once?

Irrespective of how many times you register your geofence, as long as you use the same requestId, it will be counted as a single geofence. For e.g.:

```
 mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                // Set the request ID of the geofence. This is a string to identify this geofence.
                .setRequestId(requestId)
                .setCircularRegion(latPos, longPos, mRadius)
                .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                .setLoiteringDelay(LOITERING_DELAY)
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL)
                .build());
```